# graph api for facebook friend

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

This is my code which I have used to retrieve the users friend list form the facebook but it returns empty with this error code:

{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"data":[]}}, error: null, isFromCache:false}

{

"data": []

}

My code:

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
        "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me() LIMIT 25)";

Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("q", fqlQuery);
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

Request request = new Request(session,"/fql", params,HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback(){         
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + response.toString());

        try{

            GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

            JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
            Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

            JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");

            for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                Log.d("uid",friend.getString("uid"));
                Log.d("name", friend.getString("name"));
                Log.d("pic_square",friend.getString("pic_square"));             

            }

        }catch(JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }                  
}); 
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Do give me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You just can not get list of all friends if your app was created after 30 april of 2014.

Using GraphAPI you are only able to get list of friends that are using your app, you can check the faq about 2.0 version of API.

[FAQ: API v2.0 and the New Facebook Login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq)

Also you may want to check the 'bug' report about your problem which was confirmed to be made by desing.

[No way to get all friends of "me" with a permanent ID](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1502515636638396/)

EDIT:

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("fields", "uid, name, pic_square");

        Request request = new Request(session, "me/friends", params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                if (response.getGraphObject() != null) {
                    Log.i("GA_REQ_RESPONSE", "Got results: " + response.toString());
                        //handle response
                    } catch (JSONException ex) {
                        Log.i(JSON_TAG, "JSON Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
```

Comment: My applications are used by many of my friends but also I am not getting the list of those friends who are using my apps. In such case do I need any change in my facebook app.

Comment: I'd try graph api call instead of fql, actually. [Click](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends)

Comment: ok could you please give me the code of graph api call as I could not understand the documentation of the facebook. It would be my pleasure

Comment: #bbZ is that all code. I am getting no results at all please do give me the elaborated idea or code as I am new to this Android.

Comment: #bbZ is that all code. I am getting no results at all please do give me the elaborated idea or code as I am new to this Android.